# Try to generate a post method javascript links

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I built a JAVASCRIPT into a PHP file that creates links to create links with the POST method, unfortunately it doesn't work, what am I doing wrong? which quotation marks should I choose in javascript?

```
echo '<form name="' . $i . '" method="post" action="?q=' . $query . '"><button type="submit" class="button" name="' . $i . '" value="' . $i . '">' . $i . '</button></form>';
echo '<script>
var button = document.querySelector(`form[name="` . $i .`"] > button`);
button.addEventListener(function() {
  document.querySelector("form[name="` . $i .`"]").submit();
});
</script>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\'` (backlash followed by `'`).

See this link where I tested it: https://onlinegdb.com/FF_Um4YdS

```
<?php

// random data for test
$i = "random-form";
$query = "nothing";


echo '<form name="' . $i . '" method="post" action="?q=' . $query . '"><button type="submit" class="button" name="' . $i . '" value="' . $i . '">' . $i . '</button></form>';
echo '
<script>
    var formButton = "form[name=\''. $i .'\'] > button";
    var button = document.querySelector(formButton);
    button.addEventListener(function() {
        document.querySelector("form[name=\'' . $i .'\']").submit();
    });
    </script>';

?>
```